# VBA Embed Loop within a Loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop, pivot

I'm trying to embed a loop within a loop. I have a workbook with multiple worksheets. What I'm trying to do is identify the range of each worksheet in my workbook and add an additional worksheet for each sheet to create a pivot table. I'm having trouble with embedding my For Loop for worksheet creation in the for loop of setting the worksheet ranges. My current code creates the pivot worksheets and the pivot tables but they all use the range of one worksheet only.

```
'set pivot table data range

 Dim sht As Worksheet
 Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
 For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Set dataRG = sht.Range("A4").CurrentRegion
 Next 
'verify pvt table sheets in wb

 Dim SheetNames() As Variant
 SheetNames() = Array("Test1 Pivot", "Test2 Pivot", "Test3 
 Pivot", "Test4 Pivot", "Test5 Pivot", "Test6 Pivot", 
 "Test7 Pivot")

  For n = LBound(SheetNames) To UBound(SheetNames)
      Set pvtWs = Nothing  'reset ws to Nothing
      On Error Resume Next  'ignore errors
      Set pvtWs = wb.Worksheets(SheetNames(n)) 'try to set `ws`
      On Error GoTo 0          'stop ignoring errors
      If pvtWs Is Nothing Then 'add a sheet
         Set pvtWs = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count))
         pvtWs.Name = SheetNames(n)
         
         'pivot cache and create pivot
         Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:-xlDatabase,SourceData:=dataRG)
         Set pvtTable = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=pvtWs.Cells(1,1))
         pvtTable.Name = PvtNames(n)
      End If
  Next
```

Comment: `If pvtWs Is Nothing Then Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:-xlDatabase,SourceData:=dataRG)` on a single code line. Then, comment/delete `End If`. Otherwise the code works only if no sheet `SheetNames(n)` exists...

Comment: `SourceType:-xlDatabase` should be `SourceType:=xlDatabase`  "Having trouble" is not a very useful description of the exact problem you're having with your code though.  What happens when you run your code?

Comment: @TimWilliams Sorry about that! When I run the code, pivot tables are created but they're all using the same data range from one worksheet in the workbook. I'm thinking this is because the second For loop is not embedded within the first?

Comment: From your code logic, it's not clear how you are going to associate the `CurrentRegion` data on your existing sheets as a pivot cache to the pivot tables in the new sheets you're creating. What is the correlation?

Comment: `Set dataRG = sht.Range("A4").CurrentRegion` just replaces `dataRg` with each iteration of the loop.  Where exactly is the source data for your pivot tables?

Comment: @TimWilliams The source data are the existing tabs within my workbook. I want to loop through each of the worksheets in the workbook, set the data range (to be used for pivot cache). I'm trying to have each worksheet have it's own pivot table created.

Comment: OK but how is each sheet with source data related to each of the sheets in `SheetNames`?

Comment: @TimWilliams Each of the sheets in SheetNames will hold the pivot table whose source data comes from the pre-existing sheets in the workbook. That is what I'm trying to figure out, how to connect the source data to the pivot tables in the each of SheetNames sheets. It's an issue with the dataRG.

Comment: So you have 7 existing sheets with source data? And those sheets have specific names? And each of them needs to have a pivot table sheet created (but some may already exist)?  You'd need to explicitly list out the steps the code should follow if you need help to make it do what you want.

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes. So the step by step I would like the code to follow is:

There are currently 7 existing sheets with specific team names.
1. Confirm if there exists 7 pivot sheet tabs for each of the 7 teams based on the SheetNames array.

2. Loop through the sheet names pivot sheets and if the sheet does not exist then create the sheet, if it exists then move on.

3. If it does not exist and the new ws has been created, create the pivot cache and pivot table using the source of the existing sheet. 

Sorry for the back and forth! I'm new to vba and still learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be cleaner to loop over a list of data sheet names, and use that to drive the logic.

So something like this (untested):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CheckPivots()

    Dim wb As Workbook, nm, wsPivot As Worksheet, wsData As Worksheet
    Dim SheetNames, pvNm, pvtCache As PivotCache, pvtTable As PivotTable
    Dim rngData As Range
    
    'The names of your sheets with data
    SheetNames = Array("Team1", "Team2", "Team3", _
                   "Team4", "Team5", "Team6", "Team7")
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    For Each nm In SheetNames
        Set wsData = GetSheet(wb, nm)
        If Not wsData Is Nothing Then 'data sheet exists?
            pvNm = nm & " Pivot"      'name for the pivot sheet
            Set wsPivot = GetSheet(wb, pvNm)
            If wsPivot Is Nothing Then 'need to add a pivot sheet?
                Set wsPivot = wb.Worksheets.Add(after:=wsData)
                wsPivot.Name = pvNm
                'pivot cache and create pivot
                Set rngData = wsData.Range("A4").CurrentRegion
                Set pvtCache = wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=rngData)
                Set pvtTable = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=wsPivot.Cells(1, 1))
                pvtTable.Name = "pt_" & nm 'based on source data sheet name
            End If
        End If
    Next nm    'next data sheet name
End Sub

'Return worksheet `nm` from workbook `wb`, or Nothing if no sheet with that name
Function GetSheet(wb As Workbook, wsName) As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetSheet = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
End Function
```

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams I tested the above code but I got an invalid procedure call or argument on line 14: Set wsPivot = wb.Worksheets.Add(after:=wsData)

Comment: Working OK for me...